# ERROR: connect failed - Kannel smsc configuration

Tags: kannel

I have 2 SMSC connections, the first works fine, i can send and receive messages, however the second returns the error below....not sure what am not doing right...

```
2012-09-29 09:00:24 [9921] [7] ERROR: connect failed
2012-09-29 09:00:24 [9921] [7] ERROR: System error 111: Connection refused
2012-09-29 09:00:24 [9921] [7] ERROR: error connecting to server 10.*.*.* at port 5019
2012-09-29 09:00:24 [9921] [7] ERROR: SMPP[smsc_hope]: Couldn't connect to server.
2012-09-29 09:00:24 [9921] [7] ERROR: SMPP[smsc_hope]: Couldn't connect to SMS center (retrying in 10 seconds).
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your kannel cannot connect to SMSC due to "connection refused" reason.
Can you do the "telnet" from the same machine to the specified IP address and port - I guess not ?

There might be some firewall misconfiguration either on your side or on SMSC side, making the target IP and port not reachable. If there is VPN tunnel between, is it up and running ? 
Are you using correct IP address and port ?

If there is no obvious reason on your side, you should contact support staff from the "SMSC_HOPE" and describe them the problem.